# Unable to locate package net-tools in terminal

Tags: networking

I’m using Ubuntu desktop ver 22.04.1-amd64. I’m using laptop.I can’t ping internet and I use WiFi. When I tried to install net-tools, I faced “unable to locate package net-tools. I already tried ubuntuupdates.org but it also couldn’t help me.

Thanks for your great help.

Comment: I see the package available; ie. `net-tools | 1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5 | jammy          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` so did you update your software lists (ie. `sudo apt update`) without any errors/missing lines etc.. then try and install the package again.

Comment: Can you rum a software update with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` ?

Comment: Since you "*can’t ping internet*" you seem to have a chicken-and-egg problem for downloading network software. But what makes you believe the installing net-tools or updates will solve the problem? Maybe the problem is elsewhere. Did you have it previously installed? Did you test network connectivity using your LiveUSB's 'Try Ubuntu' environment?

Comment: Your problem isn't nettools, but the fact you don't have internet. Focus on this first please ..